# Peterson's solution with waiting

Tags: c, linux-kernel, wait, critical-section

Good morning,

I'm trying to learn how to us Peterson's solution for critical section protection. Each process is trying to increment total to 100,000 and I have to make sure each child calls process#(). I also need to use the "wait" function so the parent knows when the child finishes. Once a child finishes I need to print the process ID and the amount of times process 1 interrupts process 2, and vise versa. I really have no idea what I'm doing even though I've been reading around a lot. What is this "Waiting" function I'm supposed to use? How do I use it? Why is my code incrementing to 200,000 instead of 100,000?

```
Code removed, unnecessary for question.
```

Apparently somewhere in the main function, I need to loop for the parent to wait for the child and then print the process ID of the children, but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: [Peterson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm) worked in 1981 when Peterson developed it, because microprocessors were much simpler back then. You should not be using that algorithm on a modern processor. See [this technical note](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418650(v=vs.85).aspx) for an overview of the hazards of lockless multithreading.

Comment: This is actually for a class. I'm trying to learn because the professor is incapable of teaching.

Answer (score 1):

The `wait()` command you are referring to (and `waitpid()`) is a command you use in the parent process to "wait" for a child to terminate (blocking, meaning the parent won't continue execution until the child changes state). If your child terminates and you do not `wait()` in the parent, the child process will become a "zombie". `wait()`ing effectively "reaps" the child process.

This is the signature for `waitpid()`:

```
pid_t waitpid(pid_t pid, int *status, int options);
```

`status` is a variable you can use to return some info from the child to the parent (e.g., the number of times this process was interrupted (assuming you keep track of this in the child?)); it is the exit code of the child. Let's assume you have a child with PID of 1234, you would call `waitpid(1234, &status 0)` (if you wanted to wait non-blocking, you'd have to use `WNOHANG` for options (it immediately returns if no child has exited). Check out http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid because there's cool values you can use for `waitpid()` such as `-1` to wait for *any* child to exit (this is the same as regular `wait()`). Please post comments if you have any more questions, but hopefully this is enough to point you in the right direction :).

Since you want to "loop" in the parent to wait for your children, you can either skip the loop altogether and use the normal, "blocking" wait, or you can use an infinite loop with a non-blocking wait (or a series of them, one for each child if you don't use regular `wait()`).

Just in case you didn't know, you can determine whether you are in the parent or child based on the return value of `fork()`, but I think you already knew this. So in the body of an `if` (checking for parent) is where you would do the `wait()`.

Also, is `process2()` supposed to have `while (k < 200000)`? Could this by why you say it's incrementing to 200,000?

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please upvote. If you do, I will finally have 50 rep. and can then comment on other questions/answers besides my own :).

Comment: I just did, but this is a new account so it won't show here. You've taught me more already than I've learned all semester.

Comment: Thanks much :). If you comment with more questions, I will be happy to help. I am more likely to point you in the right direction and try to let you figure it out yourself than do it for you, though (you will learn better this way :P). Also, if I am lucky enough to have this marked as the accepted answer, I will get a bunch of rep. (and it will be my first :P, I just started using this account and answering questions for the first time yesterday).

Comment: Yesss thank you! it is, because now I can comment everywhere (not just on my own answers). I hope it becomes the accepted answer, not only will it be my first, but it will get me lots of rep :). I tried hard to make this answer look nice :).